# Create Word file using Microsoft Graph api

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, office365api

I am trying to create word file using Microsoft Graph API.
[link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_put_content)

Here is the code for the same.

```
function createWordFile(token) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/FolderA/FileU.docx:/content',
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
            'authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
            "content-type": "text/plain",
            'Accept': 'application/json;odata.metadata=full'
        },
        data: 'test',
        transformRequest: []
    }).success(function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    }).error(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

File is created successfully.But it is corrupted, not opening either in Word Online or Word Desktop App.

It gives following error.

[image]

Comment: Are the file sizes for the local copy and the uploaded copy the same?

Comment: No created file size is almost 100 kb. While local copy is 2.5 MB

Comment: Looking at your sample code, I'm not seeing where you're passing the file. `data:'test'` isn't correct since the payload should be the binary file, not a string.

Comment: how to convert string to binary, is it possible in this scenario?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. You're uploading a word document so the payload should be the actual document (binnary), not a string.

Comment: ok thanks, i will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

the Microsoft Graph API does not have a method to create a file so we use the file upload method, but this case must be a binary. just remove the data attribute and it will work perfect.

```js
function createWordFile(token) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/FolderA/FileU.docx:/content',
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
            'authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
            "content-type": "text/plain",
            'Accept': 'application/json;odata.metadata=full'
        },
        data: 'test',
        transformRequest: []
    }).success(function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    }).error(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
}

token = `eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6ImFTek05SzJiU1JyWllubjhaUlYyOFpESGp6bmxtQno1Y1VmVjNHMVYxeXMiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IkN0VHVoTUptRDVNN0RMZHpEMnYyeDNRS1NSWSIsImtpZCI6IkN0VHVoTUptRDVNN0RMZHpEMnYyeDNRS1NSWSJ9.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.bErjeWOc2xOqi4PiGmRZnxrlvjHXfBTMxKRS0wD9IjyKqx8SJiHGkewsrVXjUekdO74hfixgDY4Ykf2E_dGPKdHPBtu0SScu_KT4zSSfZubs4IYu8bZL0k8c19Sv6DffC9IPayGv7un4cmObG6sUw5_N28hXtvg-HImcrwkep5gt5xmRP2yqpdL_XZ2DjTGBh_rc6ZnFIUMptl7_6s07arD9Rlheyn7faERR_94bSl4hiEGTrUlPCDuTxpo9BfWMqyAeOec4aoviCJvZD5ySfTCIRbTuyXRPndwBwNIuQX3lQRpMB1I60pGO-7gYX04vslpFwIXWQ1x2CyPsKjeLjw`

createWordFile(token)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is found is to host a .xlsx or .pptx blank file in my project. And when I need to create a new file in OneDrive from javascript, I fetch the document like below :

```
return (fetch('/assets/file-samples/template.xlsx')
            .then((res) => {
                return res.arrayBuffer();
            })
            .then((buf) => {
                return new File([buf], 'template.xlsx', {type: 
                'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'});
            })
    );
```

One I have my file. I am now able to create a document using Microsoft Graph Client Javascript SDK like below :

```
this.getSampleFile(fileType, extension).then((blankFile) => {
                    client.api('me/drive/root:/yourfolder/' + 'yourName.xlsx' + ':/content')
                        .put(blankFile).then((file) => {
                        console.log(file)
                    }, (err) => {
                        console.log(err)
                    });
                });
```